# HUD doesn't show menu entries on 18.04 Unity

Tags: unity, 18.04, hud

It's simple really; where HUD used to present a list to choose from after the first few keystrokes, it shows no list on 18.04 Unity. I've upgraded from 16.04.

For example, launch Firefox and press ALT. If you type "add" you should see four options listed to choose from on 16.04. On 18.04, I can type "add" into the HUD, but no list appears. Same for anything else I type.

This affects all applications; Libre Office, Nautilus, Gimp etc.

Please help!

Edit: Looks like my upgrade took me from 16.04 to 17.10 for some reason. The instructions I followed online said it would take me to the next LTS. I'll do another upgrade and see if that improves things.

Comment: Did you do a fresh install or upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 LTS?

Comment: I upgraded from 16.04 LTS. No menus work on Firefox, LibreOffice etc. Nothing. I've updated my question with this info, thanks!

Comment: Could be a question of when you upgraded I  guess. I upgraded May 6th and I'll upgrade again tonight probably to see what's changed. I just have to figure out how to get it to automatically reply "N" to all the 11 prompts that come up. Then I'll start it and go setup the bedroom A/C.

Comment: I don't remember answering N to any questions during upgrade. Just Y at the beginning. I'm curious about how you get on.

Comment: When you've changed a configuration file it prompts you to restore it to original state. For me it happened in systemd, pusle audio, sane, vnstat, os prober, grub and a couple of others. You may not have made changes to them.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS w/Unity to 18.04 LTS w/Unity:

[image: HUD (Alt).gif]

If you did a fresh install of 18.04 LTS w/Unity there would be no history for the HUD to display.

Comment: Wierd, I'm very surprised to see that. HUD doesn't show anything on any applications for me. Thanks for showing me.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers When did you upgrade? I imagine the upgrade program changes every business day.

Comment: I upgraded 24 hours before posting the question, so very recently. Looks like a bug report might be needed here.

Comment: I reran the 16.04 to 18.04 w/unity upgrade last night and now `F2` brings up nothing in FireFox. Not even an empty search bar. So it's a new bug since May 6th.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. When you say F2 - don't you mean the left Alt key?

Comment: Bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hud/+bug/1771173